# Google App Engine Modules + HttpServlet with static values;

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an application that delivers notifications to android and iOS devices. I am using basic scaling and have implemented logic ([modifying this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java)) so an appropriate number of workers are active at a given time without using a resident instance.

```
public class NotificationWorkerServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(NotificationWorkerServlet.class.getName());
private static final int MAX_WORKER_COUNT = 5;
private static final int MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT_WHEN_NO_TASKS_LEASED = 2500;
private static final int TEN_MINUTES = (10 * 60 * 1000);

// Area of concern
private static SyncCounter counter;

/**
 * Used to keep number of running workers in sync
 */
private class SyncCounter {

    private int c = 0;

    public SyncCounter(){
        log.info("Sync counter instantiated");
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
        log.info("Increment sync counter, workers:" + c);

    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
        log.info("Decrement sync counter, workers:" + c);
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}

/**
 * Call made from module when notification was added to task queue
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doPost(req, resp);
    // Instantiate counter with first call
    if(counter == null){
        counter = new SyncCounter();
    }

    log.info("Starting to build workers");

    for (int workerNo = counter.value(); workerNo < MAX_WORKER_COUNT; workerNo++) {
        log.info("Starting thread for worker: " + workerNo);

        // Get the current queue to check it's statistics
        Queue notificationQueue = QueueFactory
                .getQueue("notification-delivery");
        if (notificationQueue.fetchStatistics().getNumTasks() > 30 * workerNo) {
            counter.increment();
            Thread thread = ThreadManager
                    .createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                doPolling();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });

            thread.start();
        } else {
            break; // Current number of threads is sufficient.
        }
    }

    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

}

/**
 * poll the task queue and lease the tasks
 * 
 * Wait for up to 10 minutes for tasks to be added to queue before killing
 * tasks
 * 
 */
private void doPolling() {
    log.info("Doing pulling");

    try {

        int loopsWithoutProcessedTasks = 0;
        Queue notificationQueue = QueueFactory
                .getQueue("notification-delivery");
        NotificationWorker worker = new NotificationWorker(
                notificationQueue);

        while (!LifecycleManager.getInstance().isShuttingDown()) {
            boolean tasksProcessed = worker.processBatchOfTasks();
            ApiProxy.flushLogs();

            if (!tasksProcessed) {
                log.info("waiting for tasks");

                // Wait before trying to lease tasks again.
                try {
                    loopsWithoutProcessedTasks++;

                    // If worker hasn't had any tasks for 30 min, kill it.
                    if (loopsWithoutProcessedTasks >= (TEN_MINUTES / MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT_WHEN_NO_TASKS_LEASED)) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        // Else, wait and try again (to avoid tearing down
                        // useful Notification Senders)
                        Thread.sleep(MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT_WHEN_NO_TASKS_LEASED);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.info("Notification worker thread interrupted");
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                log.info("processed batch of tasks");
                loopsWithoutProcessedTasks = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warning("Exception caught and handled in notification worker: "
                + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        counter.decrement();
    }

    log.info("Instance is shutting down");

}
```

}

In a controlled testing scenario, it works just fine. However, I know static, mutable values are bad news in servlets where multiple users could potentially be connecting at the same time.

Has anyone done something similar and had issues with pushing multiple notifications to the same device, lost tasks or had idle tasks burning a hole in the bank?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to scale a basic scaling backend appropriately to handle executing tasks as efficiently and cheaply as possible. I don't want more than 5 worker threads at a time.

Comment: I have a notifications, frontend, and backend module. This is a worker servlet in the notifications module